# typescript angular 2 - creating own blob from input corrupts data

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

For learning purposes, I want to use the html input tag to select a jpeg image, retrieve the File Object, load it with fileReader and use the retrieved image string (base64) to create a new blob/file.

the service can upload the original file retrieved from the input just fine. However using my newFile the file get's corrupted and the file size somehow is larger.

I figure I'm doing something wrong with the blob constructor?

I'm using angular2 in typescript

```
<input type="file" (change)="onFileChanged($event)">

onFileChanged(event){
    if (event.target.files && event.target.files[0]) {
        let file = event.target.files[0];
        let newFile;
        let fr = new FileReader();
        fr.onload = (event:any)=>{
            let base64 = event.target.result
            let img = base64.split(',')[1]
            let blob = new Blob([window.atob(img)],{type:'image/jpeg'})
            newFile = this.blobToFile(blob,'test')
        }
        fr.readAsDataURL(file)
        console.log(file)
        console.log(newFile)
        this.service.upload(newFile).subscribe()
    }

}

blobToFile(blob: Blob, fileName: string): File {
        let b: any = blob;
        b.lastModified = moment.now();
        b.lastModifiedDate = new Date();
        b.name = fileName;
        b.webkitRelativePath="";
        return <File>blob
    }
```

EDIT------------
After finding out that fileReader is asynchronous, i've adjusted it a little bit and indeed the problem is with the blob constructor.
loggin the both the target.result of original file and new one revealed that the base64 as been transmuted. Any ideas why?

```
if (event.target.files && event.target.files[0]) {
            let file = event.target.files[0];
            let base64: string = null;

            if (/^image\//.test(file.type)) {
                let reader = new FileReader();
                reader.onload = (e: any) => {
                    console.log(e.target)
                    base64 = e.target.result

                    let img = base64.split(',')[1];
                    let blob = new Blob([img], { type: 'image/jpeg' })
                    console.log(blob);
                    let fr = new FileReader()
                    fr.onload = (event: any) => {
                        console.log(event.target)
                    }
                    fr.readAsDataURL(blob)
                }
                reader.readAsDataURL(file);
}
```

Comment: does `event.target.result` return a base64-encoded string or binary data?

Comment: returns in something like this data:image/jpeg;base64,/9j/4AAQSkZJRgABAgAAAQABAAD/2wBDAAIBAQEBAQIBAQECAg...

Comment: The code looks correct.
Do you mean that it is corrupted on the server after upload, or in the Angular app? How are you 'using' it, and what leads you to believe that it is corrupted?

Comment: well when i download it after the upload, it says the file is corrupted and can't open... 
Basically, if i just upload the original file from the input, everything works fine. If I upload the Blob/File i've created, the file is corrupted when i download it

Answer (score 3):

Modify your function like this. Because `FileReader` is asynchronous, to process the result, you need to do it inside the `onload` callback, but here, you are uploading the file outside of `onload` which at that point, is `undefined` or whatever initial value it contains.

```
onFileChanged(event){
    if (event.target.files && event.target.files[0]) {
        let file = event.target.files[0];
        let newFile;
        let fr = new FileReader();
        fr.onload = (event:any)=>{
            let base64 = event.target.result
            let img = base64.split(',')[1]
            let blob = new Blob([window.atob(img)],{type:'image/jpeg'})
            newFile = this.blobToFile(blob,'test')
            this.service.upload(newFile).subscribe()
        }
        fr.readAsDataURL(file)
        console.log(file)
        console.log(newFile) // Either prints undefined or whatever initial value it contains

    }

}
```

Comment: thanks! But now it really looks like the base64 string has been transmuted...i've updated the post above

Comment: I don't understand your new code at all, why do you have a file reader reading the file inside another file reader? You only need to read the uploaded file(s) once

Answer (score 0):

I am suspecting your code:

```
onFileChanged(event){
    if (event.target.files && event.target.files[0]) {
        let file = event.target.files[0];
        let newFile;
        let fr = new FileReader();
        fr.onload = (event:any)=>{
            let base64 = event.target.result
            let img = base64.split(',')[1]
            let blob = new Blob([window.atob(img)],{type:'image/jpeg'})
            newFile = this.blobToFile(blob,'test')
        }
        fr.readAsDataURL(file)
        console.log(file)
        console.log(newFile)
        this.service.upload(newFile).subscribe()
    }

}
```

onFileChanged(event) and (event:any), these two 'event' mean different objects. event in onFileChanged is the event object of onFileChanged. event in fr.onload is the event object of FileReader.onload. Don't you think it is confusing and might cause cross reference?